# how to put json response into table cell

Tags: json, uitableview, ios5

I am very new with ios dev and I have been struggling with almost everything so far. It's really very frustrating really.

I have put the comment /*code crashes here*/ to indicate where my app flow stops. I am requesting the json data with

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.2.4/iRestaurant/users"]];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:)
                           withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
```

The implementation for fetchedData

```
- (void)fetchedData:(NSData *)responseData {
//parse out the json data
NSError* error;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
//NSLog(@"%@", json);
NSArray* latestLoans = [json objectForKey:@"Users"]; //2
NSEnumerator* enumerator = [latestLoans objectEnumerator];
id element;

  while(element = [enumerator nextObject]) {
    Result *fetchedResults = [Result init];
    /*crashes here*/
    fetchedResults.name = [[element objectForKey:@"User"] objectForKey:@"name"]; 
    fetchedResults.email = [[element objectForKey:@"User"] objectForKey:@"name"];
    [results addObject:fetchedResults];objectForKey:@"name"]);
  }
}
```

**Result** is a custom object and is a subclass of NSObject. I have imported Result.h. I have also declared NSMutableArray *results in my current file's declaration file. I am pushing the objects into **results**. The header file for Result looks like

```
@interface Result : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int ID;

@end
```

I will be implementing cellForRowAtIndexPath and pushing the contents of results into the reusable cell.

My JSON response is

```
{"Users":
    [{"User":
        {"id":"1",
         "name":"Kishor kundan",
         "email":"kis@kun.ca",
         "password":"asdfasdf",
         "fb_id":"1234444"
        }
     },
     {"User":         
        {"id":"2",
         "name":"adsfasdf",
         "email":"asdfasdf@asdf.asdf",
         "password":"asdfasdf",
         "fb_id":"123123"
     }
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code was crashing due to object not found. My code was referencing a location that was not there. I took @btype's suggestion from my other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296920/how-to-copy-custom-nsobject-into-nsmutablearray)