# How to copy custom NSObject into NSMutableArray

Tags: ios5, nsmutablearray, nsobject

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:responseData 

                      options:kNilOptions
                      error:&error];
NSArray* users = [json objectForKey:@"Users"];
NSEnumerator* enumerator = [users objectEnumerator];
id element;
NSMutableArray *results;
Result *fetchedResults;
while(element = [enumerator nextObject]) {

   // fetchedResults = [[Result alloc] init]; // i have tried commenting/uncommenting
    fetchedResults.name = (NSString *)[[element objectForKey:@"User"] objectForKey:@"name"];
    fetchedResults.email = (NSString *)[[element objectForKey:@"User"] objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"%@", fetchedResults.name);
    [results addObject:fetchedResults];

    NSLog(@"%@", (NSString *)[[element objectForKey:@"User"] objectForKey:@"name"]); // this returns valid dump

}
NSLog(@"%d", [results count]); // returns 0
```

I don't understand wht's wrong here. I have searched through numerous tutorials and resources don't seem to get what's wrong here.

EDIT:

```
NSLog(@"%@", fetchedResults.name); // dumps null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to allocate your results array `NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]` this should help.

```
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization
                  JSONObjectWithData:responseData 
                  options:kNilOptions
                  error:&error];
NSArray* users = [json objectForKey:@"Users"];
NSMutableArray *results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (id object in users) {
    Result *fetchedResults = [[Result alloc] init];
    fetchedResults.name = (NSString *)[[element objectForKey:@"User"] objectForKey:@"name"];
    fetchedResults.email = (NSString *)[[element objectForKey:@"User"] objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSLog(@"%@", fetchedResults.name);
    [results addObject:fetchedResults];
}



NSLog(@"%@", (NSString *)[[element objectForKey:@"User"] objectForKey:@"name"]);
}

NSLog(@"%d", [results count]); // returns 0
```

Comment: I have NSMutableArray *results below "id element". won't that do ?

Comment: it crashes the app. If it helps, I have enabled ARC.

Comment: another aspect possibly related to the question. How do I make results an instance variable ? If i declare it as a property, and if i use alloc and init won't it declare the variable locally ? is there any thing i can do to fix tht ?

Comment: You have to alloc,init it one time in your init method and then use it in your class. If you alloc init it again it will be deleted and newly created.